# How to use UIViewPropertyAnimator to rotate 360º

Tags: ios, swift, animation

If I want to take advantage of user-interactive animations via `UIViewPropertyAnimator` how do I animate an object 360º clockwise?

```
// Does not animate
let animator = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: 2, curve: .linear) {
    let radians = Angle(360).radians // 6.28318530717959
    view.transform = view.transform.rotated(by: CGFloat(radians))
}
// (Using RxSwift to handle the user interaction via UISlider, 
// but that can be ignored as an implementation detail for this question.)
let scrubs = slider.rx.value.asDriver()
scrubs.drive(onNext: { (value:Float) -> Void in
    animator.fractionComplete = CGFloat(value)
})
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fortunately, `UIViewPropertyAnimator` makes this very simple (if not slightly hackish?). Just make two animations, each for 180º.:

```
let animator = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: 2, curve: .linear) {
    let radians = Angle(180).radians // 3.14159265358979
    view.transform = view.transform.rotated(by: CGFloat(radians))
}
animator.addAnimations {
    let radians = Angle(180).radians
    view.transform = view.transform.rotated(by: radians)
}
```

This will act like one animation which can be started, stopped, paused, finished or "scrubbed" via `fractionComplete`.

[image: Example playground]